# Skip dropping build files in TFS Team Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'd like to set up a TFS 2008 build in a way that it runs on every check-in and also nightly. The thing is that I'd like to keep the output from the build only for the nightly builds (with the check-in builds only acting as verification).

What is the best/suggested way of skipping the CoreDropBuild step conditionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answer on [Setting properties in triggered build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786665/setting-properties-in-triggered-build) I managed to achieve the solution by using the $(Reason) variable like `Condition=" '$(Reason)' == 'Schedule'` and setting the SkipDropBuild property to true.

You can find the details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716772(VS.90).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337598.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the retention policy to set it to Keep None.

Comment: Won't it also remove the build from the Completed builds list? How would I see what went wrong?

Comment: Yes it will. I am used to 2010 :( But you can modify the targets file on the build server (microsoft.xxx.targets in the program files) to conditionally execute the drop build step.