# Setting properties in triggered build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When queuing a new build using VS it is possible to pass in arguments to MSBuild which let's you do thing like skipping some steps of the build or do some things conditionally.

Is it possible to pass in such arguments to a build that's triggered by a checkin or a nightly build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of the $(Reason) property in your TfsBuild.proj file.

```
<Target Name="BuildNumberOverrideTarget" Condition=" '$(Reason)' == 'Schedule' ">
    <MyBuildNumberGenerator TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)" BuildUri="$(BuildUri)">
      <Output TaskParameter="BuildNumber" PropertyName="BuildNumber" />
    </MyBuildNumberGenerator>
</Target>
```

More details available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716772(VS.90).aspx